# Rails 3 w/ Devise/CanCan: POST/PUT Request Fails when loading the user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, http, devise, cancan

I am running functional tests with Test::Unit against my rails 3 application that uses Devise and CanCan to help manage users. However, I am hitting a weird issue in my requests when I make a POST or PUT to my contacts_controller. The request fails when the controller loads the User from the database, and then stops, which then results in a failed test.

Would anyone have an idea of why this is occurring?

**Console Output**

```
SQL (2.8ms)  describe `roles_users`
SQL (2.1ms)  describe `camps_users`
SQL (3.4ms)  describe `camps_users`
SQL (2.0ms)  describe `campers_camps`
SQL (2.8ms)  describe `campers_camps`
SQL (2.1ms)  describe `roles_users`
Loaded suite test/functional/camp/contacts_controller_test
Started
  SQL (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.7ms)  SHOW TABLES
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 292811013) LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `contacts`
  Camp Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `camps`.* FROM `camps` WHERE (`camps`.`id` = 665138414) LIMIT 1
  Processing by Camp::ContactsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"contact"=>{"first_name"=>"John", "last_name"=>"Doe", "email_address"=>"test@test.com", "phone_number"=>"1234567890"}, "camp_id"=>"bolo"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 292811013) LIMIT 1
  Completed   in 24ms
  SQL (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `contacts`
  SQL (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
F
Finished in 0.385608 seconds.

1) Failure:
  test_should_create_contact(Camp::ContactsControllerTest) [test/functional/camp/contacts_controller_test.rb:45]:
"Contact.count" didn't change by 1. <5> expected but was <4>.

1 tests, 1 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

Test run options: --seed 10895 --name "test_should_create_contact"
```

**Contact Test**

```
test "should create contact" do
  assert_difference('Contact.count') do
    post :create, 
      :contact => {
        :first_name => "John",
        :last_name => "Doe",
        :email_address => "test@test.com",
        :phone_number => "1234567890"
      },
      :camp_id => camps(:bolo).uri
  end

  assert_response :created
  assert_not_nil assigns(:contact)

  get :show, 
    :id => assigns(:contact).to_param,
    :camp_id => camps(:bolo).uri

  assert_response :success
end
```

**Contact Controller**

```
class Camp::ContactsController < AuthorizedController
  def create
    @contact = @camp.contacts.build(params[:contact])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @contact.save
        format.html { render :text => "contact created!", :status => :created }
        format.xml {render :xml => @contact, :status => :created, :location => @contact}
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new", :status => :bad_request }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @contact.errors, :status => :bad_request }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Authorized Controller**

```
class AuthorizedController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  check_authorization
  load_and_authorize_resource

  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    flash[:error] = exception.message
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to new_user_session_path, :status => :unauthorized }
      format.xml { render :xml => "...", :status => :unauthorized }
    end
  end
end
```

**CanCan Ability**

```
def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)

    if user.role? :admin
      can :manage, :all
    elsif user.role? :account_admin
      can [:show, :update, :destroy, :create], Camp do |camp|
        user.is_linked_to_camp?(camp)
      end

      can :manage, Contact do |contact|
        user.is_obj_linked_to_camp?(contact)
      end
    else
      cannot :manage, :all
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out is was a bug in my code. My tests were not updated to account for a new schema in the Contacts model.